# React state array seemingly reverts to original

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state array like so:

```
const [menusActive, setMenusActive] = useState([
    "MainMenu"
]);
```

It keeps track of what menus are visible. My method for this is sending a menu key/name to a function *toggleArrayItem()* which adds the key to the array if it doesn't exist, or removes it if it does:

```
function toggleArrayItem(arr, item) {
    console.log('item: ', item);
    console.log('arr: ', arr);
    let returnArray = [];
    if (arr.includes(item) === true) {
        console.log('removing item: ', item);
        returnArray = arr.filter(i => i !== item) // remove item
    } else {
        console.log('adding item: ', item);
        returnArray = [ ...arr, item ]; // add item
    }
    console.log('returnArray: ', returnArray);
    return returnArray;
}
```

When a menu item is clicked it performs the following:

```
    let existingMenu = [...menusActive];
    console.log('menu were sending to toggleArrayItem is: ', existingMenu);
    let updatedMenu = toggleArrayItem(existingMenu, menuName);
    setMenusActive(updatedMenu);
```

While debugging I check for **menuActive** updates via:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('menusActive after: ', menusActive);
}, [menusActive]);
```

The console output makes sense on the first menu click...

```
menu were sending to toggleArrayItem is:  ["MainMenu"]
MenuDock.js:36 item:  SubMenu
MenuDock.js:37 arr:  ["MainMenu"]
MenuDock.js:43 adding item:  SubMenu
MenuDock.js:46 returnArray:  (2) ["MainMenu", "SubMenu"]
MenuDock.js:54 menusActive after:  (2) ["MainMenu", "SubMenu"]
```

But doesn't when I click the same menu item again:

```
menu were sending to toggleArrayItem is:  ["MainMenu"]
MenuDock.js:36 item:  SubMenu
MenuDock.js:37 arr:  ["MainMenu"]
MenuDock.js:43 adding item:  SubMenu
MenuDock.js:46 returnArray:  (2) ["MainMenu", "SubMenu"]
MenuDock.js:54 menusActive after:  (2) ["MainMenu", "SubMenu"]
```

What happened to the second array item, "SubMenu" that was just declared as existing in **menusActive** before I tried a second menu click (which I believed would remove "SubMenu" rather than trying to add it again)?

---

## Full component

I summarised what I thought was relevant in the above, so as not to overwhelm. In case I've left anything useful out, here is the full component:

---

```
export const MenuDock = ({ side, menuJSON }) => {

    const [menuListItemArray, setMenuListItemArray] = useState([]);
    const [menusActive, setMenusActive] = useState([
        "MainMenu"
    ]);

    function handleItemClick(menuName) {
        if (menuName !== "none") {
            let existingMenu = [...menusActive];
            console.log('menu were sending to toggleArrayItem is: ', existingMenu);
            let updatedMenu = toggleArrayItem(existingMenu, menuName);
            setMenusActive(updatedMenu);
            
        }
    }


    function toggleArrayItem(arr, item) {
        console.log('item: ', item);
        console.log('arr: ', arr);
        let returnArray = [];
        if (arr.includes(item) === true) {
            console.log('removing item: ', item);
            returnArray = arr.filter(i => i !== item) // remove item
        } else {
            console.log('adding item: ', item);
            returnArray = [ ...arr, item ]; // add item
        }
        console.log('returnArray: ', returnArray);
        return returnArray;
    }



    useEffect(() => {
        // Toggle visible menus
        console.log('menusActive after: ', menusActive);
    }, [menusActive]);



    useEffect(() => {

        let jsxArray = [];

        let json2Array = [...menuJSON.MainMenu];
        let menuSort = [];
        menuSort['MainMenu'] = [];

        for (const [key, element] of Object.entries(json2Array)) {
            menuSort['MainMenu'].push(element);
            if (element.submenu !== "none" && element.submenu !== undefined) {
                let submenuKeys = Object.keys(element.submenu);
                let subKey = submenuKeys[0];
                menuSort[subKey] = [];
                element.submenu[subKey].forEach(subelement => {
                    menuSort[subKey].push(subelement);
                });

            }
        };

        for (const [key, menus] of Object.entries(menuSort)) {

            let itemArray = [];
            for (const [k2, items] of Object.entries(menuSort[key])) {

                function pcbValues(e) {
                    handleItemClick(items.submenukey);
                }
                
                itemArray.push(<MenuItem label={items.label} action={items.action} submenuKey={items.submenukey} handleClick={pcbValues} />)
            }
            jsxArray.push(<MenuList menuArray={itemArray} key={key} />);
        }

        setMenuListItemArray(jsxArray)
        
    }, []);



    return (
        <div className='storybook-menudock'>
            {menuListItemArray}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Can you show the full component? The parent block of `let existingMenu = [...menusActive];` looks like it might be the issue

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've updated the question with the full component now.

Comment: It's your classic closure problem, your `useEffect` only ever runs once due to your empty dependency list, which means your `handleItemClick` method captures the value of `menusActive` on the first render but never again. Could do a proper write up when I'm at a machine (on mobile), but ultimately you need to invalidate your handler so it captures the latest state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `menusActive` array that the handler function has in its scope is only the array from the initial render. See here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let jsxArray = [];
    // other code omitted
    for (const [key, menus] of Object.entries(menuSort)) {
        let itemArray = [];
        for (const [k2, items] of Object.entries(menuSort[key])) {
            function pcbValues(e) {
                handleItemClick(items.submenukey);
            }
            itemArray.push(<MenuItem label={items.label} action={items.action} submenuKey={items.submenukey} handleClick={pcbValues} />)
        }
        jsxArray.push(<MenuList menuArray={itemArray} key={key} />);
    }
    setMenuListItemArray(jsxArray)
}, []);
```

The stateful `menuListItemArray` changes exactly once: right after the component mounts, in the effect hook. After the effect hook runs and the state gets populated, it stays like that forever. What this means is that this section of a `MenuItem` here never changes either:

```
function pcbValues(e) {
    handleItemClick(items.submenukey);
}
itemArray.push(<MenuItem label={items.label} action={items.action} submenuKey={items.submenukey} handleClick={pcbValues} />)
```

And, at the time that the effect hook runs, the `handleItemClick` that was declared at the top of the component references the initial array - the `["MainMenu"]`, and nothing else. Calling `setMenusActive` later doesn't change the fact that the `menusActive` that the handler function that the JSX (created right after the initial render) has scope of is only the initial stateful array.

This code here is one of the reasons why putting JSX into state can easily lead to problems. A better approach is to put (serializable) plain arrays, objects, and primitives into state, and then turn the state into JSX when returning at the end of the component. Something like this:

```
export const MenuDock = ({ side, menuJSON }) => {
    const [menuListObj, setMenuListObj] = useState([]);
    // ...
    useEffect(() => {

        let jsxArray = [];

        let json2Array = [...menuJSON.MainMenu];
        let menuSort = [];
        menuSort['MainMenu'] = [];

        for (const [key, element] of Object.entries(json2Array)) {
            menuSort['MainMenu'].push(element);
            if (element.submenu !== "none" && element.submenu !== undefined) {
                let submenuKeys = Object.keys(element.submenu);
                let subKey = submenuKeys[0];
                menuSort[subKey] = [];
                element.submenu[subKey].forEach(subelement => {
                    menuSort[subKey].push(subelement);
                });

            }
        };
        setMenuListObj(menuSort);
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='storybook-menudock'>
            {
                Object.entries(menuListObj).map((key, menuItems) => <MenuList {...{ menuItems, key, handleItemClick }} />)
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

where the `MenuList` component takes the `menuItems, key, handleItemClick` props (which are now guaranteed to be from the most recent update!) and turns them into JSX itself (replacing what was previously `<MenuItem label={items.label} action={items.action} submenuKey={items.submenukey} handleClick={pcbValues} />`)

Comment: This is both detailed and informative, the explanation is much appreciated, thanks. Especially the emphasis on serializing. I've got my head around it now but the function call to *handleItemClick* is failing if the example you provided is unchanged. I'm now attempting to cater for my use of Storybook in react and to suit its variation on the usual react props. I'd imagine this is the appropriate next route to take.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by *the function call to handleItemClick is failing if the example you provided is unchanged*. You will need to change the `MenuList` component to take the changed props and to transform them into JSX itself (instead of having the parent `MenuDock` try to pass down the JSX).